# client validation function not invoked

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I want to validate two textboxes on the same asp.net page, each with its corresponding client validation function. 
I have one external js file referenced in Head section of asp.net form. 
One of the text boxes to be validated is date that works well. That is it displays an error message when an invalid date is entered. But the function for the other text box cannot be invoked. 

Here is my asp.net markup:

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" 
                                ClientValidationFunction="validateDate" ControlToValidate="txtdate" 
                                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ForeColor="Red" 
                                ValidationGroup="a" onservervalidate="CustomValidator2_ServerValidate">تاریخ نامعتبر</asp:CustomValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>

  <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
                                ClientValidationFunction="validatePhoneNumber" ControlToValidate="txtphone" 
                                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ForeColor="Red" 
                                onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate1" ValidationGroup="a" 
                                >تلفن نامعتبر</asp:CustomValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtphone" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Client validation for date happens but for phone, it does not. By the way, this is my client javascript file's contents:

```
function validateDate(oSrc, args) {
    var iDay, iMonth, iYear;
    var arrValues;
    arrValues = args.Value.split("/");
    iMonth = arrValues[1];
    iDay = arrValues[2];
    iYear = arrValues[0];

    var testDate = new Date(iYear, iMonth - 1, iDay);
    if ((testDate.getDate() != iDay) ||
      (testDate.getMonth() != iMonth - 1) ||
      (testDate.getFullYear() != iYear)) {
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }

    return true;

}

function validatePhoneNumber(oSrc, args) {
    if (args.Value.Length < 7) args.IsValid = false;
    if (isNaN(parseInt(args.value, 10))) args.IsValid = false;
    return true;
}
```

This is too frustrating for me to figure out!

Comment: what is about your server-validate-functions? the code sample u posted works fine for me without `onservervalidate` attributes

Comment: @MikhailTimofeev! do you mean we can't have both server side and client side validation at the same time?

Comment: of course you can have both of them. i mean that i checked your code and it works. But i checked it without `onservervalidate`